# Como adicionar um calendário na Frame ou Painel no Java

Tags: java, javafx

Estou desenvolvendo um projecto em Java que lida com datas. **A idéia principal é colocar um calendário de tamanho médio na tela principal**, as datas que já tiverem um evento agendado deveram possuir uma coloração (azul, laranja , etc) e ao passar o mouse sobre o menu deverá mostrar algo como um pop-up e mostrar uma descrição breve do evento.

O projecto está a ser desenvolvido usando **JavaFx** combinados com elementos da **Swing**. As minhas pesquisas só me deram o JCalendar que não satisfaz as minhas necessidades.

Qualquer dica é bem vinda.

Comment: Sobre componentes relacionados a data/calendário: JavaFX tem o [`DatePicker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm), não precisa utilizar nada de terceiros. Pode utilizar os métodos para colorir os dias com eventos agendados e o evento de "click" para buscar o evento agendado em determinado dia.

Comment: Vou tentar usar o DatePicker, mas será que você poderia me apontar alguns links com bons exemplos, ou poderia elaborar algum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente você terá que implementar um [dayCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#dayCellFactoryProperty), isso te permitirá manipular como as celulas do calendário serão renderizadas. Exemplo da documentação comentado:

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();

dp.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {

    @Override
    public DateCell call(DatePicker arg0) {
        return new DateCell() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                // Chamada obrigatória ao renderizador da superclasse
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                // Aqui estamos trocando a cor do background de um dia específico
                if(MonthDay.from(item).equals(MonthDay.of(9, 15))) {
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ff4444;");
                }
                // Aqui estamos desabilitando a data do dia seguinte
                if(item.equals(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1))) {
                    setDisable(true);
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Fica assim após a execução:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Usando essa lógica você pode implementar uma classe chamada Evento, com um LocalDate e uma descrição como atributos, e percorrer um array de eventos dentro da factory pintando-os de acordo.

Já a questão do PopUp você pode usar o método [setTooltip](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Control.html#setTooltip-javafx.scene.control.Tooltip-) que este componente herda da classe Control (O tooltip é meio bugado). Ou pode usar o [PopOver](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#popover) do ControlsFX, uma biblioteca bem difundida de componentes customizados para JavaFX.

Comment: Obrigadão Gustavo. Vou ler a documentação dos elementos que te referiste e em caso de problemas vou deixar meu comentário. E ainda não vou marcar sua resposta como melhor resposta para que mais pessoas respondam.